# Hosting two asp.net core projects in one IIS application pool

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to host two ASP.Net core application in one IIS app pool. I've created application pool and site which is linked to inetpub/myapps/myapp1 folder, then I chose Add Application in newly created site linked to inetpub/myapps/myapp2 with alias: myapp2
There is web.config in myapp1 folder with following content:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myapp1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
<system.webServer>
```

Application myapp1 is working normally but when I'm trying to add same thing to myapp2 there is configuration error appears.
I even removed handlers section, made it with different name but unfortunately nothing. 
Is there any documentation or best practice to host two asp.net core apps within one application pool?

Comment: When hosting multiple websites on a single system, you should isolate the applications from each other by running each app in its own application pool. Why are you using 1 pool for 2 apps?

Comment: First off, I agree with @Alandar: each application should get its own pool. It just keeps things cleaner and ensures that a problem in one app won't take down all the others with it. However, there is no issue in having multiple apps run in the same pool. Things like a web.config have absolutely zero effect on anything in terms of two apps using the same pool. The only issue might be if you've actually got two apps in one *site*. That's an entirely different issue, though.

Comment: I cannot even reproduce the "configuration error" you mentioned, as I can run a similar setup successfully and both apps can be served from the same pool. Provide more details please (the error page itself should contain enough information).

Comment: The problem was with application itself, so the right method to do it, it's to remove handlers section from one of applications shared in one app pool

Comment: One use case is that I have 3rd party host for a small website that I manage. They only provide a single app pool.